# Mac OS make scripts available globally

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a bunch of scripts that I want available whereever I am so I don't have to directly target the file. Similar to things like docker but how do I do this on a mac?

I have added a folder called `juicy` to `/usr/local/bin` and it now looks like:

[image]

The permissions to the folder looks like:
[image]

When I attempt to run a shell script from within the juicy folder I can get a permission denied error.

`zsh: permission denied: juicy`

Does the folder need to be running under root?

*UPDATE*
Managed to get this working by moving the files to `/Users/username/bin` and I can now (from anywhere) run the script however I need to add the script to the route of the bin folder.

- `/Users/username/bin/foobar.sh` << works
- `/Users/username/bin/juicy/foobar.sh` << does not work

Is it possible to have subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

Open your /Users/username/.bashrc or if you are using zsh your /Users/username/.zshrc and add the following:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/juicy:$PATH
```